# Why only need to change external legs in minimal-subtraction renormalization?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

For the Ch. 27 in book QFT by Srednicki, in the modified minimal-subtraction renormalization scheme($\overline{MS}$), the residue for pole at $-m_{ph}^2$ is $R$, instead of one.

1. However, I can not understand why we need only change the external leg as:

   - add a $R^{1/2}$ coefficient
   - replace the Lagrangian mass $m$ as  $m_{ph}$

but we don't need to change the internal legs.

2. Also, renormalization scheme means to determine the coefficient for counterterms, or say, determine the coefficient for $Z_i$ in Largranian:
   $$L=-\frac{1}{2}Z_\phi(\partial \phi)^2-\frac{1}{2}Z_mm\phi^2+\frac{1}{4!}Z_g g \phi^4\\=-\frac{1}{2}(\partial \phi_0)^2-\frac{1}{2}m_0\phi_0^2+\frac{1}{4!} g_0 \phi_0^4$$
   according to the answer in [Is the effective Lagrangian the bare Lagrangian?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/79112/208742), I know that renormalized $m$ is not the physical mass, but the pole of propagator is. But I am confused that: since it seems like $m_0$ is just pole according to the second line of equation above, does this mean bare mass $m_0$ is actually the physical mass(the mass what we detected)? I think so because Srednicki says "bare parameters" must be independent of $\mu$" in Ch.28. But other book, such as p.323 Peskin, says bare mass is not not the values measured in experiments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me address the quick questions you have:

> It seems like $m_0$ is just pole according to the second line of
>   equation above, does this mean bare mass $m_0$ is actually the
>   physical mass? And does the "physical mass" here means the mass what we detected?

No, $m_0$ is not the pole and it is not the physical mass. You can't just read off *the pole* from what appears in the Lagrangian.

Yes, the "physical mass" is the mass we can detect. If the theory have one-particle states, then the "physical" mass $m_{\text{ph}}$ is defined from the invariant of the momentum of the one-particle states $k^2=-m_{\text{ph}}^2$.

Now, let's clarify what is *the pole* and what are the differences between the renormalization scheme.

**The pole:**

In Srednicki's notations, the full propagator, defined via $\mathbf{\Delta}(x-y)=i\langle 0|T\phi(x)\phi(y)|0\rangle$ is given by the Lehmann-Kallen form (Eqn. 13.17):
$$
\tilde{\mathbf{\Delta}}(k^2)=\frac{1}{k^2+m_{\text{ph}}^2-i\epsilon} +\int ds\rho(s)\frac{1}{k^2+s-i\epsilon}
$$
Here the renormalized field $\phi(x)$ is assumed to satisfy Eqn. (13.2):
$$\langle k|\phi(0)|0\rangle=1$$

Looking at the first term of the exact propagator, the important point here is that it has a pole at $k^2=-m_{\text{ph}}^2$. This is *the pole* we are interested in, which define the physical mass.

On the other hand, you know that the full propagator in our perturbation theory is given in terms of the *self-energy* $i\Pi(k^2)$ by:
$$
\tilde{\mathbf{\Delta}}(k^2)=\frac{1}{k^2+m^2-\Pi(k^2)-i\epsilon}
$$
where the self-energy can be computed by summing over the 1PI 2-point graphs.

**One-shell scheme:**

In the *on-shell* scheme, we want the renormalized mass $m$ to be the physical mass. That can be done by setting $m=m_{\text{ph}}$ and impose the certain conditions on $\Pi(k^2)$ such that the full propagator has a pole at $k^2=-m_{\text{ph}}^2$. This condition determines $Z_m$.

The second condition, $\langle k|\phi(0)|0\rangle=1$ is satisfied by requiring that the residue of the full propagator at the pole is $1$.

**Minimal-subtraction Scheme:**

In the (modified) minimal-subtraction scheme, all we care about is removing the infinities. $Z_\phi$ and $Z_m$ are chosen "minimally" such that the self-energy is finite.

The renormalized mass $m$ is not the physical mass. The pole is at $k^2=-m_{\text{ph}}^2$, not $k^2=-m^2$

And since the field has not been normalized "properly", the  residue at the pole is $R=|\langle k|\phi(0)|0\rangle|^2\neq 1$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your wonderful answer! But I am confused that if bare mass, e.g. $m_0$, is not the physical mass (something we detect), why we still say bare parameters must be independent of $\mu$, as in Ch.28 by Srednicki?

Comment: @MerlinZhang The intuitive picture is like this: The bare mass is the (physical) mass when there were no interaction ($g\rightarrow 0$). In  the presence of the interaction, the free particle becomes "dressed" particle with physical mass $m_{ph}$. The difference between $m_0$ and $m_{ph}$ depends on $g$. So $m_0$ is some parameter we started off with. It shouldn't depend on anything.

Answer (score 1):

**Point 1.**
In the renormalized propagator the pole mass $m_{ph}$ is physical and independent of any subtraction scheme used to set the finite parts of the counterterms. In the on-shell subtraction scheme the finite parts of the counterterms are chosen so that $m_{ren} = m_{ph}$. In minimal subtraction $m_{ren} \ne m_{ph}$.

In minimal subtraction the lagrangian mass parameter is $m_{ren}$ and the LSZ formula has to be corrected by a $R^{-1/2}$ factor for each external particle because of the normalization of the field $R^{-1/2} \phi (x)$. The Green's function appearing in the LSZ formula already accounts for all of the interacting terms.

**Point 2.**
The bare Lagrangian is written in terms of bare (unrenormalized) fields and couplings, which are infinite. That is why of the renormalization procedure.

You write:
$\phi_0 = \sqrt{Z_\phi} \phi_{ren}$
$m_0 = Z_m m_{ren}$
$g_0 = Z_g g_{ren}$

The mass you detect is the pole mass, that is $m_{ph}$, which is related to the renormalized mass $m_{ren}$ as $\Sigma_{ren} (m_{ph}) = m_{ren} - m_{ph}$, where $\Sigma_{ren} (m_{ph})$ is the sum of all of the $1PI$ (one particle irreducible) graphs including the counterterms.

Answer (score 1):

Here we will try to answer OP's title question, which seems spurred by the following paragraph above eq. (27.6) in Srednicki's book:

> Finally, in the LSZ formula, each **external** line will contribute a factor of $R$ when the associated Klein-Gordon wave operator hits the external propagator and cancels its momentum-space pole, leaving behind the residue $R$. Combined with the correction factor of $R^{−1/2}$ for each field, we get a net factor of $R^{1/2}$ for each **external** line when using the $\overline{\rm MS}$ scheme. **Internal** lines each contribute a factor of $(−i)/(k^2 + m^2)$, where $m$ is the lagrangian-parameter mass, and each vertex contributes a factor of $iZ_g g$, where $g$ is the lagrangian-parameter coupling.

Srednicki is trying to say that the **internal**/amputated part of the connected correlator function in the LSZ formula can be calculated as a sum of amputated Feynman diagrams that are built from **free** propagators $\Delta=1/(k^2 + m^2)$, vertices $ig$, and counterterms as usual. Srednicki mentions indirectly the counterterms $Z_g-1$ for the vertex, but for some reason he does not mention the kinetic counterterm $Z_{\phi}-1$ and the mass counterterm $Z_m-1$, but of course they are also there.

The **internal free** propagators can typically not be re-summed into **full/exact** propagators a la [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/440789/2451) Phys.SE post; in particularly if they are part of a 1PI subdiagram, cf. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/348673/2451).

On the other hand, the **external** legs are already re-summed into **full/exact** propagators $${\bf \Delta}~=~\frac{1}{k^2 + m^2-\Pi}~\simeq~\frac{R}{k^2 + m_{\rm ph}^2}$$ (which carry the residue factor $R$) in order to fit into the [LSZ formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LSZ_reduction_formula).